# Why does my Perl program warn about an uninitialized value?

Tags: perl, scripting, warnings

I've written the Perl script below which generates a warning and I can't work out why.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

$status = $ENV{ 'STATUS' };
if ( $status eq "" )
{
    $status = 0;
}
else
{
    $status = 1;
}
```

It says "`Use of uninitialized value in string eq at ./x.pl line 4.`"

Line 4 is the "`if ( $status eq "" )`" line, but the variable was initialised...

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: In case you didn't know, it is generally considered better to `use warnings` rather than `-w`.  See perldoc perllexwarn for more info: http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html  Also, it is a good idea to `use strict;` in your modules.  Strict helps prevent a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$ENV{'STATUS'}` may not be defined.

If you run

```
export STATUS=blah
```

in the shell before running the Perl script, it will work.

Fix it with

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
$status = $ENV{ 'STATUS' };
if (!defined($status) || $status eq "" )
{
    $status = 0;
}
else
{
    $status = 1;
}
```

Comment: Why not `if ( defined $status and length $status ) { $status = 1 } else { $status = 0 }`?  It makes the condition a bit simpler.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is

```
$status = $ENV{ 'STATUS' } // '';
```

which will set `$status` to an empty string if it is not defined, but the `//` operator only exists in perl 5.10 and later.  The equivalent pre-5.10 syntax is

```
$status = defined $ENV{STATUS} ? $ENV{STATUS} : '';
```

although a lot of people will fake it with

```
$status = $ENV{ 'STATUS' } || '';
```

but this will change an `$ENV{STATUS}` of 0 into an empty string, which may or may not be an issue for you.

Those are all general-case answers, however.  In the particular code you posted, replacing the whole thing with

```
$status = defined $ENV{STATUS} ? 1 : 0;
```

or even just

```
$status = defined $ENV{STATUS};
```

(if you're OK with the 'not set' value being an empty string instead of 0) would be the better option.